# How to create a program group with izPack

Tags: java, izpack

Using izPack, I want to create an installation package for a suite of programs, which I want to appear as a program group, with a shortcut for each program of the suite, in the start menu.

In my install.xml file I have the tags:

```
<resources>
   <res id="shortcutSpec.xml" src="myinst_shortcutSpec.xml"/>
</resources>
```

and among the  tags I have:

```
<panel classname="ShortcutPanel"/>
```

My shortcutSpec.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<shortcuts>
    <programGroup defaultName="My Program Suite" location="applications"/>
    <shortcut applications="yes" desktop="no" initialState="noShow"
        name="Program1.exe" programGroup="yes" startMenu="yes"
        startup="no" target="$INSTALL_PATH/"/>
    <shortcut applications="yes" desktop="no" initialState="noShow"
        name="Program2.exe" programGroup="yes" startMenu="yes" startup="no" target="$INSTALL_PATH/"/>
    <shortcut applications="yes" desktop="no" initialState="noShow"
        name="Program3.exe" programGroup="yes" startMenu="yes" startup="no" target="$INSTALL_PATH/"/>
    <shortcut applications="yes" desktop="no" initialState="noShow"
        name="Program4.exe" programGroup="yes" startMenu="yes" startup="no" target="$INSTALL_PATH/"/>
    <shortcut applications="yes" desktop="no" initialState="noShow"
        name="Program5.exe" programGroup="yes" startMenu="yes" startup="no" target="$INSTALL_PATH/"/>
</shortcuts>
```

The install.xml compiles fine and generates the install.jar file, but two problems appear: first, the shortcut panel is not displayed; second, and more important, the program group with the program shortcuts is not created.

Could someone out there give some hints?